# Permanent placeholder?

Tags: javascript, input

Is there a simple way to have an input with a default starting text that can't be removed? For example, I want to input a custom url, it has "www.mysite.com/" (WITHIN the input) and I want the input to continue after that bit, but not be erasable.

Comment: Why not prepend your input with `www.mysite.com/`? (e.g. `<span>www.mysiste.com</span><input ... />`)

Comment: I know there's many workarounds (like below), it's just I'd have to custom style this one input (and container) so I wanted to know if it was possible another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
<label>
    Path: www.mysite.com/<input 
        name="path" 
        value="" 
        placeholder="images/foo.jpg">
</label>
```

... then add the prefix on the server.

You can style the background and border of the input to be transparent, and then apply a suitable background and border to the `<label>`

Comment: Well, I want it inside the input itself, *if* possible, but yes, that would work too. :)

Comment: @Brian — Styling it as suggested in the answer will make it *appear* within the input.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* set up an onKeyPress handler for the input, and then on every keypress check whether or not the input still starts with your prefix (and if not, it could add it back in).

However, I suspect that in practice this would be a terrible idea, both from an implementation and a usability perspective.

A somewhat healthier approach would be to use an onBlur event that does the same thing.  It wouldn't *instantly* update the input, but as soon as the user clicks away it would fix it.